# Eclipse error log pops up after every save

Tags: eclipse

Whenever I make any edits in eclipse (using STS) and save them the error log pops up. It's extremely annoying and I have no idea how to get rid of it. Anyone face a similar issue and how to resolve it?

Comment: What does the error log say? No one can help with so little information.

Comment: It doesn't say anything, it logs the save and pops open after save. There's no error. The issue is just that it keeps popping open after every save.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question. In the console window, there are icons on the top right.  You may have to click the vertical ellipses to see the one you need.  Uncheck the "Activate on new events".
[image: Vertical ellipse menu]